# What could be an idiom describing the action of looking for something in the wrong place?

Tags: expressions, idioms, idiom-requests

If I had to tell someone that they are searching for something (could be objects or answers to a question) in the wrong place, what idiom could be useful?

Comment: Probably related:http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/39726/phrase-or-idiom-for-funnelling-efforts-in-wrong-direction See if this helps...

Answer (score 2):

***[Bark up the wrong tree](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/bark+up+the+wrong+tree)***: can be used in that sense:

> - ***Waste one's efforts by pursuing the wrong thing or path***, as in If you think I can come up with more money, you're barking up the wrong tree.
>
>   - *This term comes from the nocturnal pursuit of raccoon-hunting with the aid of dogs. Occasionally a raccoon fools the dogs, which crowd around a tree, barking loudly, not realizing their quarry has taken a different route. [Early 1800s]*

(AHD)