# Saying for not doing something because it is futile

Tags: expressions, colloquialisms, popular-refrains

Is there such a saying? Futile may be either because it will fail or because it is unnecessary / already taken care of. I considered:
 *too many chefs spoil the broth*

and

*It's like carrying coals to newcastle*

But neither are very good...
A formal sounding colloquilism is also ok.

Comment: What's the point?

Comment: The adjective [Sisyphean](http://www.worldwidewords.org/weirdwords/ww-sis1.htm) comes to mind.  It implies an ongoing and repeated effort, fated to fail _a priori_.

Comment: You might find something to use at this question: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/64079/18655

Comment: Or at this one: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/37997/17956

Answer (score 0):

You could use

> beating a dead horse

Or

> carrying water to sea

But why not just use "pointless?"

Answer (score 0):

WOMAT (waste of money and time) may do to express that.